# How can I add custom html and styles using Vue Directives? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-directives

### The question:

How can I add custom html and styles using Vue Directives? Is it possible?
Or I have to use components?
Or using a directive to add a custom component on top of the parent component?

### Description:

I'm using VueJs + splitpanes to make some resizable panes like this:

```html
<splitpanes class="default-theme h-100">
  <pane min-size="30" size="30">
    <splitpanes horizontal>
      <pane min-size="20">
        <skyroom-users></skyroom-users>
      </pane>
      <pane min-size="30">
        <skyroom-chat></skyroom-chat>
      </pane>
    </splitpanes>
  </pane>
  <pane size="70">
    <splitpanes horizontal>
      <pane size="30">
        <skyroom-whiteboard></skyroom-whiteboard>
      </pane>
      <pane size="70">
        <skyroom-whiteboard2></skyroom-whiteboard2>
      </pane>
    </splitpanes>
  </pane>
</splitpanes>
```

**- Now I want to extend this plugin and add window controls on top of each pane**
[image: Window controls]

[image: Splitpanes]

Can I use direvctives? For example like this code:

```html
<pane v-pane-coltrols min-size="20">
  <skyroom-users></skyroom-users>
</pane>
<pane v-pane-coltrols min-size="30">
  <skyroom-chat></skyroom-chat>
</pane>
```

Comment: yes, it just took 10 sek to google it https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: @Ifaruki ok. I did a lot of googling and all of them explained changing the parent properties, not adding new child elements + styles!